# Can you add custom spring security grantedauthorities in Hybris?

Tags: java, spring-security, sap-commerce-cloud

I was wondering if anybody could explain(or point me to proper documentation) and Spring Security in Hybris. I have used Spring Security before in Java based applications and I have always enjoyed the flexibility of custom groups with specific functions. I was unable to find any documentation on how to do that in Hybris. Ideally, I would be able to add security to CMS site without creating a separate storefront. How does Hybris allow to extend Spring Security? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Generally, there is spring security config at this location. `**web/webroot/WEB-INF/config/spring-security-config.xml` . Here you can play with the configuration. [wiki page](https://wiki.hybris.com/display/accdoc50to56/Spring+Security)

Hybris supports different user groups and rules about them, which can be seen [here](https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/Managing+Users+and+User+Groups)  .

It really depends on your goal but some things can be done with Hybris [restrictions](https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/Restrictions) engine.

It is always  recommended create your own extension (extending the default one) and not using the platform extension, if i understood your idea correctly. There you can find the spring-security-config and modify it.